# Xamarin UI Test Determine Platform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to write automated tests using Xamarin UI Test, within certain parts of those tests I need to know which platform they are running on i.e. Android or iOS.

I'm struggling to find a way of doing this, does anyone know of an API to do this or any other such trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tests class have a constructor like this:

```cs
[TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
[TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
public class Tests
{
    IApp app;
    Platform platform;

    public Tests(Platform platform)
    {
        this.platform = platform;
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
    }
}
```

Later on, in you test method you could do this:

```cs
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    if (platform == Platform.Android) 
    {
        // Do specific code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer since I think this is the standard approach but I'd still like to know if there's an API call that can be used to find the platform.

Comment: From what I've used and investigate, this is the way to do it.

Comment: I don't think we have any API for this. This is how you do it.